3D Coordinate Transform Using $T$ and $R$ Matrices
I'm using a fiducial to calibrate a camera's position.
I have a translation $T$ of the camera to the fiducial and rotation $R$ of the fiducial relative to the camera.
I want to use the fiducial as a 'flat' origin point and find the camera's position and angle relative to that.
I've read up on rotation matrices and thought it may be the dot product, but that doesn't seem to work. I'm struggling in 3d.
How would one use $T_{c\to f}$ and $R_{f}$ to calculate $T_{f\to c}$ and $R_c$?

$T$: Translation matrix $(X, Y, Z)$:

$Y$: Dist away from the camera.
$X$: Dist horizontally from Y-axis
$Z$: Dist vertically from Y-axis.

$T=\begin{bmatrix}
0.437 \\
0.277 \\
0.952 \\ 
\end{bmatrix}$
$R=$ : Rotation matrix (3, 3):
$R=\begin{bmatrix}
0.943 & -0.299 & 0.148 \\
0.212 & 0.879 & 0.428 \\
-0.259 & -0.372 & 0.891 \\ 
\end{bmatrix}$

I found the solution via this StackOverflow post.
I'm leaving this question up for others like me who struggled to find the answer.
To transform from Camera-centric coordinates to fiducial centric:
$R_{c}={R_{f}^\mathbf{T}}$
$T_{f\to c} = T_{c\to f} * R_{c}$
This yields the camera position & angle using the fiducial as the origin.
